# SharePoint Foundation 2013 - Advance Search Webpart

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, search

Is "Advance Search Webpart" is available in SharePoint Foundation 2013?

Comment: To give you a quick reply - No, they are not. Search webparts are part of the enterprise license.

Comment: check this, if you can do it in ur environment http://www.helptheusers.com/blog/?p=220